# Doing actions on a list from the shell

Tags: bash, shell, freebsd

I have a list of packages I want to deinstall. The deinstaller program `pkg_deinstall` doesn't take a list of packages as parameter to deinstall. How would I deinstall from the list (like a foreach loop)?

```
[root@fbsd01 /usr/ports/editors/vim]# pkg_info | grep proto| sed 's/\([a-z0-9]*\).*/\1/'
bigreqsproto
compositeproto
damageproto
fixesproto
fontsproto
inputproto
kbproto
randrproto
renderproto
xcb
xcmiscproto
xextproto
xf86bigfontproto
xineramaproto
```

I would think a command similar to this would work, but I have to pass the list as a parameter and not a stream: `pkg_info | grep proto| sed 's/\([a-z0-9]*\).*/\1/' | head -n 1 pkg_deinstall`

If you could give me some clues as to what program and syntax to use, that would be helpful. I know since it's unique you might have a hard time coming up with an exact answer. If my question is too complicated, maybe someone could show me how to do actions on an `ls` of files in a dir.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the most basic 'foreach' there is `xargs`, it reads some parameters and append them to some other command line. For example you may try:

```
> cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd | xargs -n1 echo user:
```

Note that you should pass a `-d'\n'` argument to `xargs` in the case usernames could contain space characters.
To append all¹ parameters to the same command use:

```
> cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd | xargs echo users:
```

For more general loops, you can use this:

```
> cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd | while read i; do echo $i; done
```

This time, `$i` can be placed anywhere in a sequence of one or more commands.
Inputs are read one line at a time, and stored in the variable `i`.
It is also possible to split² the line and store it in several variables:

```
> cut -d: -f1,6 /etc/passwd --output-delimiter=' ' | \
  while read i j; do echo home directory of user $i is $j; done
```

Note that for loops over raw filenames, the following is better (see comments):

```
> for i in *.txt; do echo file: $i; done
```

—
<sup>1. More precisely: as many as the system will allow.</sup>
<sup>2. According to the `IFS` variable</sup>

Comment: In your case, since the `pkg_deinstall` command allows multiple arguments, a simple `pkg_info | grep proto | sed 's/([a-z0-9])./\1/' | xargs pkg_deinstall` should be enough.

Comment: Yes, this is what I needed. I got it working. Thank you very much!

Comment: Parsing the output of `ls` to act on files is [to be avoided](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Use shell globing such as `for file in *; do [...] done` or `find -exec` instead. In this OP's question they already have a list of packages generated, so piping that into a while read loop is probably fine, but for file names it is not!

Comment: @Caleb it should be ok as long as I do a regex with sed right?

Comment: @Stephane: Why don't you make your comment your answer, avoiding the problematic `ls`?

Comment: @everybody: Thanks for the comments, I've added some more details. Yes, `ls` was a simple, but bad example.

Comment: @EhevuTov: It really doesn't have anything to do with the use of `sed` so much as the potential contents of the output and the fact that `ls`'s output is 100% ambiguous.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez: Usually using the OP's example is the best way, they weren't working with files in the first place.

Comment: @userunknown: I worked this up using the OP's question, but since that isn't about files in the first place the issue didn't come even come up.

Answer (score 3):

There are two main ways to convert an output stream into an argument list. The quick (and sometimes dirty) way to do this is with `xargs`. By default it accepts a standard input stream and runs a command with each line of the input as a separate argument. You should always be careful about the format of the input because spaces and other characters are easy to misinturpret when passed as arguments. Package names, however, are relativly safe. They shouldn't include shell wildcard characters or newlines or anything crazy, so here's what it would look like for your command:<sup>[3]</sup>

```
$ pkg_info | grep proto | sed 's/\([a-z0-9]*\).*/\1/' | xargs pkg_deinstall -n
```

A frequent case is that you actually need to run the command once for every line being processed. In this case the `-n` argument comes in handy. You can use `-n1` to run them one at a time, or even `-n10` to run them in batches of ten.

```
$ [pipline] | xargs -n1 pkg_deinstall -n
```

Now let's say you have a need to add another argument after the automaticly generated once. In this case you can use '-I' to specify a string to replace with the auto-generated arguments. This will also allow you to do things like quote the argument if necessary. You can then format where the arguments will get placed like this:<sup>[1][2]</sup>

```
$ [pipline] | xargs -n1 -I{} pkg_deinstall -n "{}" --trailing-argument
```

If you wanted more control or to run multiple commands for each line of input, your next option is to use a loop like this:

```
$ [pipline] | while read line; do
      echo "Uninstalling $line..."
      pkg_deinstall -n "$line"
  done
```

Note that the `pkg_deinstall` automatically uses the expression as a partial match glob, so be careful about what you pass to be uninstalled. Passing the base name of some system component will uninstall not only that component, but everything that has a name like it or depends on it! This could be catastrophic, so always carefully check your package set. You can use `-n` to do a dry run that shows what would be done without actually doing it<sup>[3]</sup> and/or `-i` to run each step interactively.

<sub>[1] I used `{}` for because find and other similar exec functions use this format, but any unique string will do.</sub>
<sub>[2] The `pkg_deinstall` command doesn't have any arguments that would come after the patern, so this is an example only!</sub>
<sub>[3] I added `-n` to all my examples so that if you copy and paste the code it won't actually do anything, just show you a test run.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Not to take away from the other answers...  This is just one more way to do it:

```
for pkg in $( pkg_info | grep proto| sed 's/\([a-z0-9]*\).*/\1/' ) ; do
    pkg_deinstall $pkg
done
```

Quoting is a nightmare in example, so I personally tend to use `| while read foo ...` more often than not.

Comment: Make that `while IFS= read -r foo; do …` (`-r` to disable the special treatment of backslashes and `IFS=` to avoid stripping initial whitespace).